# Synonym of "game assistant"

Tags: synonyms, sports

Well, I'm asking this for two reasons. First, because of my combined clumsiness for sports and English. And second, because due to the whims of my boss I have to keep using flowery terms in the scientific paper that I'm writing.

Even if I can be done with the generic word "agent", I need to put a metaphor of a "game" for something as mundane as a "stochastic process". I basically need two words, one of them can be "player", although it doesn't hurt if it needs to be different, and the other something that roughly means "game assistant", "game facilitator", "batboy" (I can't use this because my boss will think is too vulgar), in practically any sport. I'm asking for a word like this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot fathom what a *game assistant* does during a game. Please can you edit your question to define the game assistant's behaviour?

Comment: @MattЭллен: Look to my comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54467/16940, it is the closest that I can get, as there is no game by any reasonable definition of the word.

Comment: *Someone who sweats a lot, during the game, for the players to have fun* - I'm afraid I'm still none the wiser. The players themselves surely do that?

Comment: @MattЭллен: "Caddie", the handyman for golfers, was the word that I selected at the end. It is somebody that  carries the poles, while the  players just enjoy the walk. As I said in my question, "batboy" would also do it, but because I'm in Europe, I have better chances with golf instead of baseball :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Player, Wingman

Actor, Support

Talent, Agent

Boss, Henchman

Leader, Follower

Primary, Secondary

Master, Apprentice

Main, Ally

Protagonist, Accessory

Master, Attendant

Hero, Lackey

Lion, Gopher

Prince, Man-at-arms

Golfer, Caddie

Player, Referee

Bidder, Dummy

Player, Partner

Answer (score 0):

*Coach*, as in sports instructor or trainer, may suit.

Comment: Thanks, but I need something more on the sense of "somebody that sweats a lot during the game for the players to have fun". So, neither arbitrator nor coach would really do :-( .